# Using PowerShell to discover all valid IP's over a VPN

Tags: powershell, vpn

I am attempting to learn PowerShell. I am currently working on how to find the IP address that are remote. I am having trouble getting all active remote IP's.

```
Set-Location “C:\Users”
Remove-Item “.\*\Appdata\Local\Temp\*” -recurse -force
Set-loaction C:\Users\%UserName%\Appdata\Local\Temp
Remove-Item “.\*\Appdata\Local\Temp\*” -recurse -force
```

As you can see I am also attempting to delete all the temp files on said computers.

Please remeber I am new at this and I am asking for help.

Comment: `%UserName%` is for cmd. The PowerShell equivalent = `$env:USERNAME`. There is an easier way by using `$env:LOCALAPPDATA`, which already gets you to the Appdata\Local for the **current** user. Tip: do **not** use curly so-called 'smart-quotes' in code, but use straight ones instead. The curly thingies may lead you into weird, hard to spot errors.

Comment: @Theo thank you for your assistance. I think may not been clear. I need to find all available IP's on the network (VPN and Local). I did use your suggestion and it does find the local IP, however like I stated I would like to find all active IP over a VPN and LOCAL computers... Again thank you for your suggestion